# Excel: Average Difference in a single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset like this:

```
10, 23, 43, 45, 56;

12, 25, 21, 23, 40;
```

I want to know the average of the difference between the two rows like

> mean (10 - 12, 23 - 25, 43 -21 ...)

Of course, this is only an example and the actual rows are hundreds of element long. I would like to compute the average of the difference without having to compute somewhere the difference and then having the average. (The sheet is already pretty big)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically, what you are asking for is identical to:

`=AVERAGE(A1:E1)-AVERAGE(A2:E2)`

Regards

Comment: Tom Sharpe's reply may be useful to those who ended up in this question! Still, this answer is right, clear, and damn i'm so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX((A1:E1)-(A2:E2), , ))
```

[image]

Comment: Why `INDEX`? To avoid it being array formula?

Comment: Yes, INDEX with no row or formula argument is its array format so no CSE. (but you stll need those empty comma placeholders)

Comment: or you could use 0 instead of a space?

Comment: Yes a zero is the same as space. It means all rows or all columns referenced in the first argument.

Comment: @Jeeped Just curious: Is using `INDEX` in this way preferable to using array formula? What difference does it make in the actual calculation?

Comment: None that I'm aware of and the only time saved is your own when a moronic fellow office worker enters into the formula with F2 or clicking in the formula bar. They won't know how to CSE so using INDEX means you don't have to go fix it for them.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If there were missing values in one range or the other, you would need something like

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:G1,A1:G1,"<>",A2:G2,"<>")-AVERAGEIFS(A2:G2,A1:G1,"<>",A2:G2,"<>")
```

(I have tested it with blanks in G1 and F2)

[image]